# the marked line gives me compilation error?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
public void generateMap(ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter> weakFoes, ArrayList<NonPlayableFighter>
strongFoes){
    Map[0][0]=new FoeCell(strongFoes[(int)(Math.random()*8)]);
    for(int i=0;i<15;i++){
        Map[(int)(Math.random()*9)][(int)(Math.random()*9)]=new FoeCell(weakFoes[(int)(Math.random()*7)]);
    }
    Random rand;
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((5 - 3) + 1) + 3;
    for(int i=0;i<randomNum;i++){
        Map[(int)(Math.random()*9)][(int)(Math.random()*9)].equals(Collectible.SENZU_BEAN); 
    }
    Map[(int)(Math.random()*9)][(int)(Math.random()*9)].equals(Collectible.DRAGON_BALL);
}
```

Comment: What error do you receive ?

Comment: Yea. Yea... What error?

Comment: The line is probably : `Map[0][0] = new FoeCell(strongFoes[(int)(Math.random()*8)]);` but the format of the question was really not clear, so it has been formatted but I would guess that this was the problematic line.

Comment: You're getting a little hostility from the crowd here, because a) we don't know which line you're talking about (we don't see any mark to indicate which line), and b) you haven't told us the compilation error message. Help us help you. Give us enough to work with.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
Map[0][0]=new FoeCell(strongFoes[(int)(Math.random()*8)]);
```

won't compile because you're using array access notation (with the square brackets: `strongFoes[somenumber]`) on an `ArrayList`. `ArrayList` is not an array, it's a `List`. You can't use the `[` and `]`, you have to invoke methods on it like `get(someNumber)` and `set(someNumber, someObject)`.

That specific line of code should read something like:

```
Map[0][0]=new FoeCell(strongFoes.get((int)(Math.random()*8)));
```

You could get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there aren't enough elements in the `List`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html for more information on how to use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: I really wonder how `new FoeCell()` could return anything else than a `FoeCell` instance. I don't know what `Map` is or what it's suppose to be, but it's not just a problem of ArrayList

Comment: @Marc-Andre I'm guessing that `Map` is defined as `public static FoeCell[][] Map = ...`

Comment: But yes, so many problems here

Comment: indeed if `Map` is defined as this it should work, anyway that's why we need more information from the OP and he would benefit from a good code review!